# Code works in CLion but not when using vim editor in Ubuntu command line terminal

Tags: c, loops, ubuntu, infinite-loop, clion

This block of code is supposed to calculate the users heart rate, and then ask them if they want to repeat the process, and inform the user if they have made an invalid input when typing 1 or 0. it works perfectly fine in Clion, but my school requires we submit assignments through a command line terminal interface running Ubuntu. When using vim editor, and executing my code in the terminal, I get stuck in an infinite loop because even when I type 0 to quit, the INVALID INPUT text is displayed, and I am asked to enter 1 or 0 again. That infinite loop does not happen when I run the exact same code in CLion. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int pulse, restHeartRate, goAgain = 1;

    do{
        printf("\n\nTake your resting pulse for 10 seconds.\n");
        printf("Enter your pulse rate:  ");
        scanf("%d", &pulse);

        restHeartRate = pulse * 6;

        printf("\n\nYour resting heart rate is %d.\n", restHeartRate);

        printf("\n\n");
        printf("\nTry again? \n1 for yes, 0 for no: ");
        scanf("%d", &goAgain);
        while (goAgain != 1 && goAgain != 0){
            printf("\nINVALID INPUT\n1 for yes, 0 for no: ");
            scanf("%d", &goAgain);
        }
    } while (goAgain == 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Why won't this work in Ubuntu using vim?

I tried running the code in both Clion and the Ubuntu command line interafce and it only works in Clion.

Comment: You don't run programs using `vim` — or, at least, you compile the program first and then run it, but you usually don't run it from inside `vim`.  In what way doesn't it work?  What tells you it isn't working?  What's the error message?  How are you compiling it?  How are you running it?  You should check the return value from `scanf()` to spot errors like "Quit" instead of `1` or `0`.  Consider exiting the loop unless the answer is `1`.

Comment: Did you miskey any input? Such as entering a non-integer? That will cause the input to block.